# dynamic LINQ query

Tags: .net, sql, wpf, linq

Hi I am using dynamic linq, using PredicateBuilder of LinqKit.

If you look at the code, line after TODO comment, i want to accomplish something like
Lets say there are 2 objects in objectList viz. object1, object2
(object1.property1 AND object1.property2) OR (object2.property1 AND object2.property2)

I know the line after TODO is incorrect, but I am looking for correct version of that line.

```
  var finalPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True();

  foreach (var item in objectList)
  {
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True();
    predicate = predicate.And (p => p.Description.Contains (item.property1));
    predicate = predicate.And (p => p.Description.Contains (item.property2));
    //TODO: 
    finalPredicate = finalPredicate.Or(predicate);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the final predicate:
`
finalPredicate{f => (True OrElse Invoke(f => (((True AndAlso Invoke(p => p.ef.Contains(value(Service1+<>
      c__DisplayClass2).item.FilterDomain), f)) AndAlso Invoke(p => p.fname.Contains(value(Service1+<>
            c__DisplayClass2).item.ff), f)) AndAlso Invoke(p => p.subject.Contains(value(Service1+<>
                  c__DisplayClass2).item.fs), f)), f))}System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ds.Data.vView,bool>> `

Comment: this is the error message: The parameter 'f' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution the other day from other stackoverflow question, I apologize that I don't have the link to that post now, but this is the solution

When using predicate within predicate, you have to Expand() it everytime. See the next line of TODO with the fix. This solves my problem.

Also fixed the true false problem but that was logical mistake.

```
var finalPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False();

  foreach (var item in objectList)
  {
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True();
    predicate = predicate.And (p => p.Description.Contains (item.property1));
    predicate = predicate.And (p => p.Description.Contains (item.property2));
    //TODO: 
    finalPredicate = finalPredicate.Or(predicate.Expand());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var finalPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True();
```

should be

```
var finalPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False();
```

True or x = always true (x is ignored).

False or x = x.

---

The other problem is the way loop variables are captured in lambda expressions.

```
foreach (var item in objectList)
{
  var loopItem = item;
  //now use loopItem instead of item.
  ...
}
```

Comment: @David, thanks. But I'm getting this error : The parameter 'f' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression.

Comment: data = abc.AsExpandable().Where(finalPredicate).ToList();

Comment: @NSingla, where exactly is that exception thrown? Do you only get it when `finalPredicate` is initialized to false, and does the `for` loop run more than once? What I think is that the exception is getting caused by something in the `for` loop, but the problem code doesn't get evaluated in your version because the `true or x` structure short-circuits before `x` is evaluated (I hope that makes sense as I wrote it). I don't know PredicateBuilder well enough to be sure about this, but that's my first thought.

Comment: @Justin, at this line data = abc.AsExpandable().Where(finalPredicate).ToList();

Comment: @NSingla Okay, that makes sense. That line is where the data would actually pass through the expression you've constructed. Before that, it will only exist as an expression tree. So I think the problem isn't the first line or the `finalPredicate = finalPredicate.Or(predicate);`, it's something about the sub-expressions you're folding in. Unfortunately, I don't know PB well enough to know that exception, so this is as far as I can take you.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't finalPredicate start out as False? This will always evaluate to true.

---

**EDIT:**

Having looked at the exception code you posted, I think you could think of it **VERY** roughly as:

(pseudocode)

```
finalPredicate = 
    true || 
    (true && 
        p.ef.Contains(item.FilterDomain) && 
        p.fname.Contains(item.ff) && 
        p.subject.Contains(item.fs)
    )
```

Note that that's NOT what it *really* means; you're building an expression tree, which is different from classic, imperative C# (so this edit is probably begging for downvotes). But it might make it easier for you to think of it that way.

So you have at least two issues here:

- What I and others were pointing out was the first `true || ...`. A true value || anything will always produce True. So if you initialize `finalPredicate` to True, the whole thing is going to be True no matter what. In fact, [your other expressions might not even get evaluated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), which is why you only see this exception when you initialize `finalPredicate` to False. That's the only time your code is getting hit.
- You probably have a bug somewhere in the `for` loop, and my guess is it has to do with those calls to `Contains`. However, without more knowledge of your situation or the data involved, it's hard to tell more than that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And - starts with True, Or - starts with False. Right?

Comment: @NSingla - Correct, if you mean what I think you mean. But finalPredicate is only hitting the `Or` method. Your sub-predicates are the ones `And` is operating on.

Comment: finalPredicate{f => (True OrElse Invoke(f => (((True AndAlso Invoke(p => p.ef.Contains(value(Service1+<>
      c__DisplayClass2).item.FilterDomain), f)) AndAlso Invoke(p => p.fname.Contains(value(Service1+<>
            c__DisplayClass2).item.ff), f)) AndAlso Invoke(p => p.subject.Contains(value(Service1+<>
                  c__DisplayClass2).item.fs), f)), f))}System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ds.Data.vView,bool>>

Comment: this is the error message: The parameter 'f' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression